# Enquiry on Definition of Product topology

Tags: general-topology

In **James.E.Munkres** in product topology it is written in the definition that

**if X and Y are two topological spaces Then the product topology on X×Y is the topology having as basis the collection C of all sets of the form U×V, where U is an open subset of X and V is an open subset of Y**.

Now after that they have already proven  that $C $ is not a topology. Then what does the product toplogy means?? Any help would be appriciated.  thanks.

Comment: It's a basis for the topology (i.e., those sets _generate_ the topology by taking arbitrary unions.)

Comment: It says $C$ is a basis for the product topology, not that $C$ is the product topology itself.

Comment: But the basis generated space will be the topology. In this case what will be the topology will look like

Comment: Unions of those sets. For example, in $R^2$, the basis elements are rectangular regions (with edges parallel to the axes), but the union of two rectangular regions need not be a rectangular region.

Comment: More precisely, for $R\,{\times}\,R$, the product topology basis elements are _open_ rectangular regions (possibly empty, possibly unbounded) with edges parallel to the axes. To get all the open sets, you need arbitrary unions (i.e., finite unions won't suffice to get all open sets)

Comment: Oh. OK.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the definitions of topology and basis.  Munkres defines a topology as

> **Definition.** A ***topology*** on a set $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of $X$ having the following properties:
>
> $(1)$ $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{T}$.
>
> $(2)$ The union of the elements of any subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$.
>
> $(3)$ The intersection of the elements of any finite subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$.

In contrast, Munkres defines a basis for a topology as follows:

> **Definition.** If $X$ is a set, a ***basis*** for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathfrak{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called ***basis elements***) such that
>
> $(1)$ For each $x\in X$ there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
>
> $(2)$ If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$, then there is a basis element $B_{3}$ containing $x$ such that $B_{3} \subset B_{1}\cap B_{2}$.

Later on, Munkres proves a lemma that gives the connection between the two.

> **Lemma $13.1$.** Let $X$ be a set; let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a basis for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$.  Then $\mathcal{T}$ equals the collection of all unions of elements on $\mathfrak{B}$.

Therefore a basis need not be a topology, but when we take all unions of elements of the basis then we obtain a topology.  In regards to the product topology, we can think of it in regards to this lemma.  Munkres defines the product topology as follows.

> **Definition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces.  The ***product topology*** on $X\times Y$ is the topology having as basis the collection $\mathfrak{B}$ of all sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ is an open subset of $X$ and $V$ is an open subset of $Y$.

Specifically what that means is that if you take an arbitrary open set $W$  in the product topology on $X\times Y$ then it in light of the lemma we know that $$W = \bigcup_{j\in J}U_{j}\times V_{j}$$ where $J$ is some index set, $U_{j}$ is open in $X$ for each $j\in J$ and $V_{j}$ is open in $Y$ for each $j \in J.$